# Google Analytics Regex for Page URL Matching

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm working on a Google Analytics Regex that will match either path:
`/checkout/` or `/randomText/cart.php`

`randomText` will display random text for each URL.

This is what I have so far: `/checkout/|/?/cart.php`

Just wanted to double check if it's correct or if there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^/checkout/|/.*/cart\.php$
```

This will filter exactly "/checkout" or "/[random text]/cart.php".

If you know that the random text is just numbers or letters or even the length, then you can refine the regex.

Comment: Thank you! This works. Random text is a mixed of letters and numbers.